# EJB 3 JMS Configuration loading Exception || WAS 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere, ejb-3.0

I have successfully configured JMS topics and Queues for IBM Webshere.

I have used JMS topic in such a way that listener class is base of all sub classes.
Like in following manner:

```
public class Base implements MessageListener {
  public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) { } }

@MessageDriven(activationConfig={
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="messagingType",propertyValue="javax.jms.MessageListener"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType",propertyValue="javax.jms.Topic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination",propertyValue="topic/Test"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="messageSelector",propertyValue="RECIPIENT='TestR'")},messageListenerInterface=MessageListener.class)

public class TopicSubScriber extends Base {    

}
```

I got the following error:

```
the class contains the @MessageDriven annotation but is not a valid
  message-driven bean: no message listener interface can be determined
```

**Note:** These both classes are in different modules.

It seems that it is not loading the Base class. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tested my JMS onfigurations that are working fine with testing code ...
But got the above exception in production code...

Comment: try adding implements MessageListener on TopicSubScriper as well (even if the super class got it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also Applied following IBM Web sphere fix pack 7 but no vain..
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM70521

Problem is resolved by implements MessageListener on TopicSubScriper as well (even if the super class got it) .. As this solution  has no fictional impact ,so i am happy:)

Many thanks SiB & Aviram Segal for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar [thread](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21595667) at IBM Websphere the answer says

> Answer
>
> *Ignore this error message as there is no functional impact.*

[Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpo.html) says

> *It is recommended, **but not required**, that a message-driven bean class implement the message listener interface for the message type it supports. A bean that supports the JMS API implements the **javax.jms.MessageListener** interface*

Still if you want to avoid the error message, I feel you can try `implements MessageListener` on `TopicSubScriper`